# Is it possible to Load c library in Window Store App?

Tags: visual-c++, dllimport, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to Load c library in Window Store App? If yes, tell me how to load. My code is as follow.

I declared in PDFconverter class as follow.

```
[DllImport("gsdll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_new_instance")]
private static extern int gsapi_new_instance(out IntPtr pinstance, IntPtr caller_handle);
```

Access Class as follow:

```
PDFConvert converter = new PDFConvert();
converter.Convert(inputpath, outputpath);
```

Comment: Sure it is possible. You just need to write a proxy dll. Or you may attach your programm to the process and inject some code to load your dll file. Bit ether this is IMHO hacking. What do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am trying to load Ghostscript library from Metro Style App. This library is regarding converting of pdf to image. I have already tried to load but didn't success. If there is a way how to load library. Please tell me how to load.

Comment: Add the code... What have you tried exactly?

Comment: Hello Rekire, these tow links[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685805/where-should-i-put-c-sharp-dll-in-metro-style-appc][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685567/load-c-library-gsdll32-dll-from-metro-style-app-c-sharp] told me that Win32 library could not used in WinRt. But you answer me yes. If yes, how can I reference, pls explains to me.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?  It should work.  In WinRT they have to loadPackagedLibrary function to replace loadlibrary/loadlibraryex but it works kinda the same.  For managed code using dllimport should be fine.  Whats the error you are getting?